# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-debugging, testing, hardhat-deploy, mocha

I am following FreeCodeCamp's javascript Blockchain/SmartContract course. Facing issue at lesson 9 staging test. Contract deployment and unit tests are running fine. Running mocha test on sepolia network. Getting this error at `await expect(raffle.accounts[0].to.be.reverted)` line inside Promise object.
Here's my staging test script:
**Raffle.staging.test.js**

```js
const{ getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const{ developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config");
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");

developmentChains.includes(network.name) 
    ? describe.skip 
    : describe("Raffle staging test", function() {
        let raffle, raffleEntranceFee, deployer

        beforeEach(async function() {
            deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
            raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer)
            raffleEntranceFee = await raffle.getEntranceFee()
        })

        describe("fulfillRandomWords", function() {
            it("works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner", async function() {
                // enter the raffle
                const startingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLatestTimestamp()
                const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()

                // /*setup the listener before enter the raffle, just in case the blockchain moves really fast */
                await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    raffle.once("winnerPicked", async () => {
                        console.log("WinnerPicked event fired")
                        try {
                            // add our asserts here
                            const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
                            const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
                            const winnerEndingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                            const endingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLatestTimestamp()

                            await expect(raffle.accounts[0].to.be.reverted) // after picking up a winner no account should be there in raffle
                            assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")
                            assert.equal(recentWinner, accounts[0].address)
                            assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                            assert.equal(winnerEndingBalance.toString(), winnerStartingBalance.add(raffleEntranceFee).toString())
                            resolve()


                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error(error)
                            reject(error)
                        }
                        
                    })
                    // Then entering the raffle
                    await raffle.enterRaffle({value: raffleEntranceFee})
                    // check the balance after entering
                    const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                    // and this code won't finish until our listener has finished listening
                })

            })
        })
})
```

Here's my contract: **Raffle.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Raffle__TransactionFailed();
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

/**
 * @title A sample Raffle Contract
 * @author Vikash Rajak | @mohmayaGit
 * @notice This contract is for creating an untemperable decentralized smart contract
 * @dev This implements Chainlink VRF v2 and Chainlink Keeper
 */

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Type declarations */
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    } // uint256 0 = OPEN, 1 = CALCULATING
    // This is to limit the participant from entering into lottery if it is not open
    // or while generating random winner
    // We could have used 'bool', but it has two outputs only.
    // We can specify more than 2 outputs using enum.
    
    /*State varible*/
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    /*Lottery variables */
    address private s_recentWinner;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    /*Events*/
    event raffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event requestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event winnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    /* Functions */
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2, // a mock deployment would be required for this
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN; // or, RaffleState(0)
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }
        // Allow players to enter only when it is open
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__NotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        // emit an event when we update a dynamic array or mapping
        // name events with function name reversed
        emit raffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * for automation of random number task
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink keeper nodes call
     * they look for 'upkeepNeeded' to return true
     * The following should be true in order to return true:
     * 1. Our time interval should have passed
     * 2. The lottery should have at least one player, and have some ETH
     * 3. Our subscription is funded with LINK
     * 4. The lottery should be in 'open' state.
    */
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /*checkData*/
    ) public override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /*performData */){
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);

    }
    
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
        // request the random number
        //do something with this number
        //2 transaction process

        // while requesting random number, don't allow users to enter the lottery
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        if(!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(address(this).balance, s_players.length, uint256(s_raffleState));
        }

        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit requestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /*requestId*/,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 winnerIndex = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[winnerIndex];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        // after winner selection, reset the players array and
        // allow new participants to enter
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        // require(success);
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransactionFailed();
        }
        // keep track of the list of previous winners
        emit winnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    /* View/Pure functions */
    
    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    // function selectWinner() public view returns (address) {
    //     uint256 rn = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, s_players.length)));
    //     uint index = rn % s_players.length;
    //     return s_players[index];
    // }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
        return s_raffleState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure/*'view' won't be allowed, cuz not reading from storage */ returns(uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS;
    }

    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }

    function getLatestTimestamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }


}
```

Here's the hardhat config file: **hardhat.config.js**

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("hardhat-contract-sizer")
require("dotenv").config()

const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
const OPTG_RPC_URL = process.env.OPTG_RPC_URL
const OPTG_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.OPTG_PRIVATE_KEY
const OPTIMISM_API_KEY = process.env.OPTIMISM_API_KEY
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
            blockConfirmations: 1,
        },
        optimistic: {
            url: OPTG_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [OPTG_PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 420,
            waitConfirmations: 6,
        },
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 5,
            waitConfirmations: 6, // adding block confirmation to give contracts ample time to get deployed on Etherscan
        },
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
            waitConfirmations: 5,
        }
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: {
            sepolia: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
            // polygon: POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY,
        },
        // customChains: [
        //     {
        //         network: "sepolia",
        //         chainId: 11155111,
        //         urls: {
        //             apiURL: "https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/ETHERSCAN_API_KEY",
        //             browserURL: "https://sepolia.etherscan.io",
        //         },
        //     },
        // ],
    },
    gasReporter: {
        enabled: true,
        currency: "USD",
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
    },

    solidity: "0.8.7",
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0,
        },
        player: {
            default: 1,
        },
    },
    
    mocha: {
        timeout: 600000, // 600 sec
    }
}
```

And here's the helper hardhat config file: **helper-hardaht-config.js**

```js
const networkConfig = {
    default: {
        name: "hardaht",
        interval: "30",
    },
    
    11155111: {
        name: "sepolia",
        vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x8103B0A8A00be2DDC778e6e7eaa21791Cd364625",
        entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane: "0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c",
        callbackGasLimit: "500000",
        interval: "30",
        subscriptionId: "2450",

    },
    31337: {
        name: "localhost",
        entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane: "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15",
        callbackGasLimit: "500000",
        interval: "30",
        subscriptionId: "0",
    },
}

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]

module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
}
```